# type of query TIMEDIFF in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
  ALTER TABLE personne
ADD NBHEURES integer as (TIMEDIFF(FINRES,DEBUTRES));
```

this code give me error .Type of FINRES and DEBUTRES are TIME

Answer (score 0):

The TIMEDIFF() function returns the difference (expressed as a time value) between two time/datetime values. So the data type of NBHEURES should be time. Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE personne
ADD NBHEURES time ;
UPDATE personne set NBHEURES = TIMEDIFF(FINRES,DEBUTRES) ;
```